# Date and time format in crontab outputs time with forward slash as separator instead of colons

Tags: bash, cron, macos

I am piping output of urlwatch to a log file and having an issue where the colons in time format using `%T` are being replace by forward slashes on OS X.

Date variable:

```
DATEVAR='+%Y_%m_%d %T'
```

This is the crontab:

```
*/2 6-23 * * * /usr/local/bin/urlwatch | /usr/local/bin/ts '[\%b \%d \%H:\%M:\%S] -' > /Users/name/Library/Logs/Urlwatch/urlwatch\ "$(date "$DATEVAR").log"
```

The backslash after `/Urlwatch/urlwatch` is to escape the following space. Removing that and using an underscore doesn't resolve this issue. Exhanging `%H:%M:%S` for `%T` doesn't resolve this issue.

The output:

```
urlwatch 2020_04_12 19/08/00.log
```

Running `date` in terminal gives me: `Sun Apr 12 19:23:59 CDT 2020`

and...

```
$ DATEVAR="+%Y_%m_%d %T"
$ echo | > /Users/name/Library/Logs/Urlwatch/urlwatch\ "$(date "$DATEVAR").log"
```

Outputs this file: `urlwatch 2020_04_12 19/26/01.log`

notes: `ts` is a non-standard osx binary I installed with brew install moreutils.

Comment: [Related?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13298434/10765659)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Of course (shaking head) Thank you!